# Issue with Hibernate commit after exception while persisting a list of objects

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I'm facing an issue when trying to commit with Hibernate after an exception occurs during the persistence of a list of objects. My code utilizes Hibernate to persist objects in a database, and I would like to ensure that the objects that were successfully processed up to the point of the error are saved in the database, even after an exception.

Currently, my method looks like this:

```
private void persist(List<T> entities, Boolean commitInError, boolean isSaveOrUpdate) {
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            
            for (T entity : entities) {
                if (isSaveOrUpdate) {
                    session.merge(entity);
                } else {
                    session.remove(entity);
                }
            }
            
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                if (commitInError) {
                    try {
                        transaction.commit();
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        throw e2;
                    }
                } else {
                    transaction.rollback();
                }
            }
            throw e;
        } finally {
            close();
        }
    }
```

I'd like to know if anyone has encountered a similar issue when trying to commit with Hibernate after an exception during the persistence of a list of objects. Is there any recommended solution or approach to handle this situation?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I use hibernate 6.3.1.Final

Comment: The recommended approach, don't. When an exception occurs the state of the session is invalid / uncertain. If you want to commit in between use multiple transactions or use savepoints.

Comment: Could you give an example please?

Comment: Your code also looks flawed, as you are re-using a `transaction` field which is probably at the class level, which feels wrong, especially if that is in a singleton object. Start a transaction, and each x elements do a flush, clear and commit and start a new transaction. That way you will only loose the last x records (maximal) that you processed. Or, if your database supports it, you can use savepoints and do intermediate commits on a single transaction (but that depends on your database).